# Wrapping an image strip around a circle in photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I need to wrap this image strip around a circular frame,how can I do it in photoshop?[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To achieve the rough and ready result below I:

1. Stretched the images height by about 50%
2. Flipped it vertically
3. Hit filter > distort > polar coordinates (rectangular to polar) > OK

Depending on required size for display this may or may not be OK. I suspect the only way to do this  nicely is manually, one figure at a time.

In fact perhaps you could use this rough version as a guide on one layer, and manually place the figures. At least you'd have a handy guide to desired angles.

[image]

Comment: I m working it out manually as you rightly said that it is the only way to do it with perfection. Thank you for your help anyways.

Comment: No problem, good luck